# Thucydides mark step failed and continue test execution

Tags: thucydides

I have thucydides + easyb.

I have some method with @Test annotation. For examle:

```
@Test
public void Step1(){
    assertThat(true).isTrue();
}
@Test
public void Step2(){
    assertThat(true).isFalse();
}
@Test
public void Step3(){
    assertThat(true).isTrue();
}
```

In test story methods are execute in next order:
step1
step2
step3

In step2 AssertionError has threw. And step3 will skipped.

I need that step2 in report will marked as failed. And step3 will execute and mark as passed in report.

I can wrap assert in try catch, but I can't find any ways to mark step2 failed with thucydides callbacks.

Can anyone help me, please?